# TypeError - Unable to Continue with Catch Exception

Tags: javascript, exception

I'm unable to get the script to continue running when it runs into an exception. It will regardless stop working at the .split

I tried a few levels of catch exception and have gotten the same result.

From my understanding , the script should continue running but i'm getting a different result with this.

Please advice if i did overlook anything.

```
    function general(html){
    try {
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: ""+url,
        synchronous: true,
        onload: function(response) {
            var e = response.responseText.split('<source src="')[1].split('"')[0];
           }
        });
    } catch (exception) {
        //Ignore Exception & Continue
    }
}


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at Function.onload (script.html?id=8705b42e-a72f-4a45-a971-8ecdea05d096:545)
at <anonymous>:2:491
at eval (eval at exec_fn (X:1), <anonymous>:31:148)
```

Comment: You can't wrap an async process in try...catch it is going to already be past it by the time the callback is called. Use the try..catch inside the callback.... or just check responseText first

Comment: @PatrickEvans is there anyway i can check a split? because responseText will for sure return something

Comment: I can do a if (e === undefined || e === null) after but that wont work too, the error will appear first

Comment: Your error is telling you that `responseText` doesn't hold a value, ie `undefined` check that using an if statement before trying to use it. `if(response.responseText){}`

Comment: The ResponseText does hold a value, its the split that is missing therefore undefined , i printed and did a if else statement

Comment: @CodeGuru No, not the `split` is missing, `responseText` is missing. Read the error message _carefully_.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, i basically checked if the string exist first.

Only proceed if the string exist. Dirty fix but it works.

Code to detect string

```
(ES6)
var string = "foo",
    substring = "oo";
string.includes(substring);
```

My fixed code

```
 var substring = "<source";
        var result = response.responseText.includes(substring);
        var e = null
        if(result === true){
            e = response.responseText.split('<source src="')[1].split('"')[0];
        }
```

Comment: Checking if a variable / property holds a value before trying to use it is not a dirty fix, it's how you are supposed to do programming. You always check that your input is what you are expecting. Also your "fixed" code will still error out if your request doesn't return a proper response, ie `responseText` again equals `undefined` as `undefined` does not have an `includes()` method